# Get local file using <a href=... in Firefox

Tags: html, file, firefox

Hi I want to get my local file. So I put in my *.html file :

```
<a href="file:///home/dawid.lenkiewicz/232889_kwiecien.csv" type="application/excel" class="excelLink">
```

but it doesn't work. But if I just copy and paste "file:///home/dawid.lenkiewicz/232889_kwiecien.csv" into a new window I get my file. How to solve this problem in my application?

Comment: And how will others get this local file? It will not exist in the same location on their computer.

Comment: Later it will be on a server and I will change the path. Now I just test it on my local machine

Comment: please read how to use the [SO editor](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: You need to place the file on the server then call it. It is consider a security issue if you call a local file.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_don%27t_work) you need to create a user.js file inside your Firefox profile folder with the following entries:

```
user_pref("capability.policy.policynames", "localfilelinks");
user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.sites", "http://localhost http://127.0.0.1");
user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.checkloaduri.enabled", "allAccess");
```

Using that you should be set.

But you could also use relative paths to your file. Or rather put it in your webserver's root folder which would be preferrable because you could show your website to others.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in the latest version of Firefox (11)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox disables this functionality for security reasons.

In a development environment, I would suggest setting up a simple web server such as Apache, and running everything through that. You can use something like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) to get up and running quickly.